# Creating a composite object from two other core data objects

Tags: ios, arrays, object, core-data, swift

I have 2 Core Data classes. **Patient** and **Handover**. One Patient can have multiple Handovers.

**Patient.swift**

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class Patient: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var id: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var firstName: String
    @NSManaged var lastName: String
    @NSManaged var personalNumber: String
    @NSManaged var handovers: NSSet
}
```

**Handover.swift**

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class Handover: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var date: NSDate
    @NSManaged var status: String
    @NSManaged var time: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var patient: Patient
}
```

I need to display a list of patients who have handovers for a given date. And it needs to be sorted by `time`.

Here's an example of a result set I get.

```
handovers = db.loadHandovers(NSDate.date())
for handover in handovers {
    let handover = handover as Handover
    println("\(handover.time) - \(handover.patient.firstName) \(handover.patient.lastName)")
}
```

[image]

Notice there are three Handovers for the patient *Anna Andersson* at 8 and four Handovers for the patient *Göte 2 Andersson* at 8. I need these to be grouped by the Patient. But there's another catch. If the same Patient has more Handovers at different times, they are to be treated as a separate group. For example, you can see that *Anna Andersson* has another handover at 14. This needs to be a separate group.

```
+------+-------------------+-------------------+
| TIME |      PATIENT      |  NO. OF HANDOVERS |
+------+-------------------+-------------------+
|      |                   |                   |
| 08   |  Anna Andersson   |  3                |
|      |                   |                   |
| 08   |  Göte 2 Andersson |  4                |
|      |                   |                   |
| 10   |  Göte 2 Andersson |  1                |
|      |                   |                   |
| 11   |  Göte 2 Andersson |  1                |
|      |                   |                   |
| 14   |  Anna Andersson   |  1                |
+------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

I created a separate class called `CompositeItem` to hold these.

```
import Foundation

public class CompositeItem {

    var patient: Patient!
    var handovers: [Handover] = []

    init() {

    }
}
```

Where I'm stuck now is how to iterate through the `handovers` array and group them and create composite objects.

I have a for loop iterating through the retrieved handovers.

```
private var compositeItems: [CompositeItem] = []

handovers = db.loadHandovers(NSDate.date())

for handover in handovers {
    let handover = handover as Handover

    if compositeItems.isEmpty {
        let item = CompositeItem()
        item.patient = handover.patient
        item.handovers.append(handover)
    } else {
        // How can I check if the current Handover object has the same Patient and the time as the last added Handover.
        // And add it to the last `item`'s handovers array if they do match.
    }
}
```

My question is how can I check if the current Handover object has the same Patient and the time as the last added Handover. And add it to the last `item`'s handovers array if they do match.

I'd really appreciate any help. This part has me stumped.

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you creating this composite?  Is it just so you can reproduce the nice table of time/patient/#handovers?  If so, you can achieve it with a well-crafted fetch request.

Comment: I only need to display the time and the patient name in a tableview like [this](http://i.imgur.com/KK3JsqU.png). When you tap on one row, the user is navigated to a new screen to display a list of all the handovers. [This](http://pastebin.com/6PdN37Pd) is the fetch request I use to retrieve the handovers.

Comment: I have a suggestion which uses the database to do the grouping for you.  I will outline it in a separate answer, but I'm not yet using Swift, so will have to leave it to you to code.

Comment: No problem. I can try and convert it to Swift. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually managed to solve my problem going with the old route I tried. Below is the code I wrote.

```
let handovers = db.loadHandovers(NSDate())

for handover in handovers {
    let handover = handover as Handover

    if compositeItems.isEmpty {
        let item = CompositeItem()
        item.patient = handover.patient
        item.handovers.append(handover)

        compositeItems.append(item)
    } else {
        let lastCompositeItem = compositeItems.last!
        let lastHandover = lastCompositeItem.handovers.last!

        if handover.patient.id == lastHandover.patient.id && handover.time == lastHandover.time {
            lastCompositeItem.handovers.append(handover)
        } else {
            let item = CompositeItem()
            item.patient = handover.patient
            item.handovers.append(handover)

            compositeItems.append(item)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `NSFetchRequest` to do the grouping for you.  In order to do this, you will have to change the fetch to return its results as an array of dictionaries (`resultType = DictionaryResultType`), rather than an array of objects.  You then specify the properties that you want to group by (`propertiesToGroupBy`) eg. patient name and time, and those you want to be included in the results (`propertiesToFetch`) eg. patient name, time, count.  Try inserting the following into your loadHandovers function:

```
public func loadHandovers(date: NSDate) -> [AnyObject] {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
    let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Handover", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)
    let datePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "date > %@ AND date < %@", getStartDate(date), getEndDate(date))
    let descriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "time", ascending: true)

    let patientNameExp = NSExpression(forKeyPath:"patient.name")
    let patientNameED = NSExpressionDescription()

    patientNameED.expression = patientNameExp
    patientNameED.name = "patientName"
    patientNameED.expressionResultType = NSAttributeType.StringAttributeType

    let timeED : NSAttributeDescription = entityDescription?.attributesByName["time"] as NSAttributeDescription

    let countExp = NSExpression(format: "count:(name)")
    let countED = NSExpressionDescription()
    countED.name = "count"
    countED.expression = countExp
    countED.expressionResultType = NSAttributeType.Integer32AttributeType

    fetchRequest.resultType = NSFetchRequestResultType.DictionaryResultType
    fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = [timeED, patientNameED, countED]
    fetchRequest.propertiesToGroupBy = [timeED, patientNameED]

    fetchRequest.entity = entityDescription
    fetchRequest.predicate = datePredicate
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [descriptor]

    var error: NSError?
    let result = managedObjectContext?.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error)
    return result!
}
```

(Apologies for my Swift syntax, this shows no errors in my Playground but may need optionals sorting out etc).  You should receive an array back, with each element being a dictionary.  The dictionary will have keys "time", "patientName" and "count", which you can use to populate your cells.

Comment: Hi pbasdf, I managed to solve this using my old method I was going to take. I posted my solution as an answer here. Thanks for trying to help. Appreciate it :)

Comment: Hello pbasdf. I'm faced with a similar issue once again and this time I thought of going ahead with doing the grouping from the database side itself. The current problem is very similar to this and using the same database and the entities. In your answer, you have this line `let patientNameExp = NSExpression(forKeyPath:"patient.name")`. But as you can see in my entity class, there is no `name` attribute but two separate attributes as `firstName` and `lastName`. How do you handle grouping when you have two attributes like this instead of one?

Comment: I would create NSExpressions and NSExpressionDescriptions for each (`lastName` and `firstName`) separately, and then add both EDs to the `propertiesToFetch` and `propertiesToGroupBy`.

Comment: Alright. Thanks. By the way what does this line do `let countExp = NSExpression(format: "count:(name)")`? I don't have an attribute called `name`.

Comment: countExp is used to count the number of handovers for each time/patient (for the "No. of Handovers" column in the table in your question).  Changing it to "count:(time)" should work.

Comment: I did the changes and ran the app but it crashes with the following error **'Attribute/relationship description names passed to setPropertiesToFetch: must match name on fetch entity**. [This](http://pastebin.com/sBpFvtGH) is the code I have now. All the attribute names are correct though.

Comment: Hmmm, sorry, I will need to dig out my original test app.  Can you test (by removing each in turn from propertiesToFetch) to see which ED is causing the problem?

Comment: The problem seems to be with `timeED`. If I remove that, the crash doesn't happen.

Comment: Strange.  Try amending it as follows: `fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = ["time", patientFirstNameED, patientLastNameED, countED]` ie. replace timeED with "time"

Comment: Tried that. No luck :(. The crash still occurs.

Comment: Sorry, @Isuru, I have no idea why that error is occurring - in my test app it is working fine.  My only suggestions are a) clean the build, b) create an NSExpression(forKeyPath:"time") and an associated NSExpressionDescription, and use that in place of timeED.  And c) if those fail, post a fresh question so others can assist.

Comment: Have just found the problem - you need to move the line where you set the entity for the fetch (`fetchRequest.entity = entityDescription`) BEFORE the lines where you set the properties to fetch.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me out. That resolved the issue. Now I have to see if it returns the correct result set. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can store your composite items in a dictionary instead of an array. The dictionary key can be the `NSManagedObjectID` of the patient object so that you will not get multiple patients. So the dictionary might look like this:

```
let patientsWithHandovers = Dictionary<NSManagedObjectID,CompositeItem>()
```

When you iterate through your handovers you can check if the patient already exists in the dictionary and if yes, append the handover in it's handover array.

If the patient is not in the dictionary, create a new one:

```
patientsWithHandovers[patient.objectID] = CompositeItem(...)
```

---

Example for iterating through an array and fill a dictionary with objects

```
let numbers = [1,3,2,4,5,6,11,13,12,15,8,21,22,31]  // array with even and odd numbers
var numberDict = Dictionary<String,[Int]>()  // dictionary for separating evens and odds

// initializing the dictionary
numberDict["even"] = []
numberDict["odd"] = []

for number in numbers {
    if number % 2 == 0 {
        numberDict["even"].append(number)
    }
    else {
        numberDict["odd"].append(number)
    }
}
```

Now the numbers are separated in a dictionary with two keys: *even* and *odd*

I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I have one question. You've mentioned that using the `NSManagedObjectID` of the patient object to prevent duplicate Patients. But I need multiple patients to be in, only in different time slots. Will using `NSManagedObjectID` interfere with this or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: The NSManagedObjectID is *uniqe*. I see in the image you mentioned in your comment above that the patient's ID is not the correct approach. You should probably use the combination of date and time as the dictionary's key and then store all patients for that date and time in an array, which is the dictionary's value.

Comment: Can you please provide a simple example on how to iterate through an array and add values to Dictionary? I'm not familiar with generics so I'm struggling to get the hang of it. Doesn't have to be related to my problem. Just a example would be really helpful.

Comment: I have edited my answer above to include some sample code on this. Hope you get the idea.

Comment: Hi zisoft, I managed to solve this using my old method I was going to take. I posted my solution as an answer here. Thanks for trying to help. Appreciate it :)